# setup rails-api gem with rabl-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

Im trying to use the rabl templating system from within rails-api.

rabl looks for templates in the view path, which rails-api omits.

How would i setup rabl-rails, i have included the below lines into my Controller.

```
        include ActionController::MimeResponds
        include ActionController::ImplicitRender
        respond_to :json
```

However:
json: @deal uses standard rails rendered. 
Renderer.json(@deal) in undefined, i assume it would be available with rabl.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: raised a [feature request](https://github.com/ccocchi/rabl-rails/issues/86) on _Github_

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
config.view_paths = ['/app/views']
```

to `config/initializers/rabl_init.rb`. No need for `rabl-rails`, use plain `rabl`, no need for those `include`'s, no need for `respond_to`.
Render with:

```
render 'foo/bar' # will render app/views/foo/bar.rabl template
```

Comment: `rabl` is not there for windows, huh?

Comment: @ZekeDran isn't it? Mind sharing your experience?

Comment: I'm kinda stuck right now, if I use `rabl`, i get this [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770776/symlink-notimplementederror-rabl) on windows, and if I use `rabl-rails`, I am not able to use it with `rails-5-api`...! Not really comfortable with `jbuilder` :(

Comment: doesn't work with rails-5-api..! Someone already raised the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358632/rails-api-only-ignoring-rabl-files). I'm getting blank responses, its not even looking inside `/app/views`

Comment: seems to be bcoz of `broken-link` between _controllers_ and _views_ which used to be there till `rails 4` possibly with some _middleware_ which was gotten rid of in `rails 5`