# Rails api-only ignoring rabl files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rabl

I have what I believe to be a very simple app, with Rails 5 (API only) but for some reason it is returning an empty response while it should be returning a json object (using RABL)

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_exercise, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @exercises = Exercise.all

    # Works
    # render json: @exercises

    # Blank response
    render :index
  end
end

# app/views/exercises/index.json.rabl
collection @exercises
attributes :id, :name
```

If I use a direct render (commented) it works properly, but with the rabl template it is blank... any thoughts?

Comment: in fact, it returns blank for **whatever** is typed after `render` (though statuses are processed perfectly). Tried `render 'exercises/index'`, `render 'index'`.

Comment: Also tried renaming the `rabl` file with and without `.json`

Comment: Is there any other view registered for that action, e.g. `index.html.erb`? What is the output of `render text: @excercies.inspect` ?

Comment: Seems Rabl doesn't support Rails 5 yet, unfortunately.

Comment: I think the issue is also related to the libraries loaded. Have you loaded Rabl? Because the `--api` flag limits the amount of libraries that Rails loads, and may not have rendering setup in such a way that Rabl hooks into it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `config.view_paths = ['/app/views']` to your configuration.